# Gapless looping in unity3d

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine

I've been struggling with this for some days already now ... :(

I've read these threads: [Gapless-MP3-playback](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/66090-Gapless-MP3-playback), [Gapless looping on iOS](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/127767/gapless-looping-on-ios.html), [Gapless looping on iOS](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/207243/gapless-looping-on-ios.html) [Producing seamless looping mp3s](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/29947/producing-seamless-looping-mp3s.html). Also a bit of theory here: [mp3Loops](http://www.compuphase.com/mp3/mp3loops.htm)

I am doing as instructed: Import WAV files, select MPEG encoding, check the "gapless looping" box

- *just a note for future googlers. In very old versions of Unity, there was a "gapless looping" button (removed since about 2014). In fact, that button was completely broken and did nothing.*

and make it loop:

```
    var gameObject2 = new GameObject("MyObject");
    audioSource2 = gameObject2.AddComponent<AudioSource>();

    var filename = "test01_1152x";
    audioClip2 = Resources.Load (filename) as AudioClip;
    audioSource2.clip = audioClip2;
    audioSource2.loop = true;
    audioSource2.Play();
```

However the "pop" sound is terribly obvious.

I wonder what am I missing?

Checking "gapless looping" is just a bit better but it does not avoid the "pop" sound 100%.
If the file given is wrong or not best for this situation, what conditions should the file fullfill in order to have a nice gapless looping bgm?

These are the pictures of various settings I've tried, including the original wave file

Original Wave: Loops nicely, because it is WAV.
[image]

Compressed as MPEG (Non gapless looping selected), "pop" sound is super obvious while listeninig it.
[image]

Compressed as MPEG (Gapless looping selected), "pop" sound is still obvious, just a bit better than setting.
[image]

Comment: @notthetup I did try turning off harwdaware decoding. No audible change :(.

Comment: @kreys Yes, I am trying with short pieces. It is on purpose because with short pieces the "pop" sound was more obvious.

Comment: I would try with longer pieces anyway. In my opinion this problem could be caused by having to loop that piece ~8 times per second, instead of looping some normal clip once every 10-30s. Maybe audio card or the drivers combination can't keep up with such frequent changes of played music. I still recommend checking loops with longer clips ;)

Comment: I tried with a bit longer file, which is about 2 seconds. The results where the same. I don't think is an audio card or drivers related thing. However I do suspect it is related to the file.

Comment: Just for anyone googling here, the four comments here are completely wrong and unfortunately the chosen answer is 100% incorrect.  The answer to the question is dead simple, **You can't loop an mp3 in Unity. It is clearly explained in the manual.**.  You just use wav

Comment: (As it even says *in the question*, the wav loops correctly!  Heh!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is easy to see that the clips are not well suited for gapless looping. 
I don't need to play those clips to listen to the clic and the pop you mention, it is pretty obvious from the waveform you posted. Think of audio clips as repeatable textures or seamless patterns, the start and end needs to match, and the easiest way to achieve this is by cutting the clip when the amplitude of the wave is 0.

See how smooth is the "sin" wave on the WAV format compared to the other formats? The reason is that compressed format like MP3 loss quality and information, deteriorating the quality. See that the compressed waves don't start smooth, they start with a straight line which will render as noise.

So if you increase the kbps (less compression) you will have far better results. But still I strongly suggest that you go with the WAV format for better results, this is what Unity states for short sounds:

"As a general rule of thumb, Compressed audio (or modules) are best for long files like background music or dialog, while Native is better for short sound effects"

[Audio Clip - Importing Audio Assets](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioClip.html)

And regarding "have a nice gapless bgm" you need to use a good tool for that, one that allows you to cut, trim, stretch and test the audio loop before you export it to a wav file. I personally use Cakewalk SONAR. Here is an image of you compose a nice looping sound, see how I cut the sound when the amplitude is near "0".

One last thing, if you have several sounds playing simultaneously you won't be able to take advantage of hardware decoding of MP3, most mobile devices only allow for one sound to be decompressed by hardware, the other sounds will be rendered by the CPU.

[image: Loop Construction on SONAR X1]

In this other picture I show how to properly cut a loopable sound from a longer piece that does not fade like in the previous example.

[image]

Comment: I understand. I am using short sounds just to make the "pop" sound obvious, quicker and easier to detect to my ears. In reality I am using about 90 secs long background music. I have a question. I kind of understand the logic behind so I see that cutting the *song* someplace near 0 is good, but does this mean it must be 0?

Comment: Originally the song I was trying to loop was ending and starting in zero but it was not slowly going to zero like in your picture, it was more like an abrupt down in the end. Do you think this kind of song is suited for a gapless looping background music? As you noticed, I am a newbie in sound engineering area.

Comment: Nacho, it does not need to be cero like in my picture. It just needs to be seamless, and since it is very hard to know the exact decibels or amplitude of the wave, it is just easier to cut at 0 db. The abrupt down is fine, as long as you cut it at 0 and the start of the song is also from 0. I will try to add second picture explaining this.

Comment: I really appreciate the pictures! I will try to get a real background song and post my results!.

Comment: For anyone googling here, this answer is **utterly incorrect**.  You simply cannot loop an mp3 in Unity, you have to use a wav. It says this right in the manual and literally on the Inspector when you drop a file in.  Unity can, of course, instantly gapless loop sounds (short or long) - only wav files accepted.

Comment: BTW, it is *absolutely impossible* to edit an mp3 in this way for Unity (for whatever reason you may want to edit it) ... since ... ***Unity reframes all mp3s !!!!!!!***.  You simply literally ***can not*** control mp3 tails like this in Unity.  (As it says in dozens of places in the doco - use wav for this.)

Answer (score 7):

## You can't loop an mp3 in Unity.

It is clearly **stated in the manual**.

Indeed when you drop an mp3 in to Unity it literally **shows an alert** that you cannot loop mp3s in Unity.

## Simply convert to Ogg or Wav.

That's all there is to it.

Same sound as mp3 versus wav:

[image]

Obviously it is trivial to convert audio files between formats; use any software on your Mac or PC to do so. (Example, [TwistedWave](https://twistedwave.com).)

(Note: The discussions in the other answers about how to loop smoothly in an artistic sense, **are completely unrelated to the question of Unity3D / mp3 looping** - which is trivial, you can't loop an mp3 in Unity.)

Comment: Regarding the part you said ***This is all clearly mentioned and explained in the manual BTW.*** , could you quote the docs or even better give us a link to such mention?

Comment: This is obvious but, sometimes we cannot just switch to wav (because the file is quite large and in wav format would be hundreds of MB) or ogg (because for example iOS does not support them yet). Although, I appreciate this answer because it clarifies my procedure is not mistaken but there is something in Unity is not working as we expect.

Comment: Also in Unity 5, now the gapless button disappears.

Comment: Hi Nach (1) it's simply not possible to gapless loop an mp3 in Unity, it's just that simple.  (2) you can convert any file, even 100s of gigabytes, from mp3 to ogg or wav in a few seconds

Comment: By the way, it's absolutely not possible to "make it work" by matching the frame size: because Unity changes the file!