# Unity3D stream audio file from disk

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building an audio player that needs to be able to play files from disk which aren't available at build time (so users can put their own music in). OGG/WAV files are fine and I need to support both Windows and OSX. I've tried using the [WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class as such:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class LoadAudio : MonoBehaviour
{
    AudioSource audioSrc;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        if(audioSrc == null) audioSrc = new AudioSource();
        StartCoroutine(LoadTrack(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Track.ogg")));
    }

    IEnumerator LoadTrack(string filename)
    {
        var www = new WWW(filename);

        while(www.progress < 0.2)
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("Progress loading {0}: {1}", filename, www.progress);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }

        var clip = www.GetAudioClip(false, true, AudioType.OGGVORBIS);

        audioSrc.clip = clip;
        audioSrc.Play();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

However, when I run this my debug log message prints out that there is 0 progress a few times, then I get an error that can't be seen in the Console. In the Editor log, I can see this error:

```
Error: Cannot create FMOD::Sound instance for resource D (Operation could not be performed because specified sound/DSP connection is not ready. )
UnityEngine.WWW:GetAudioClipInternal(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, AudioType)
UnityEngine.WWW:GetAudioClip(Boolean, Boolean, AudioType) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\artifacts\generated\common\runtime\UtilsBindings.gen.cs:334)
<LoadTrack>c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets\LoadAudio.cs:27)
```

This error looks similar to the one raised in this [Unity bug report](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/fmod-sound-instance-for-resource-error), however that was supposedly fixed in version 5.3.0 and I'm using 5.3.4.

Assuming this isn't a bug in Unity, what am I doing wrong? If this is a bug, then does anyone know a workaround?

EDIT: I submitted a bug report to Unity and they confirmed that they have reproduced the bug, but it may be a long time before it is fixed. As such, I would appreciate a way to work around this issue.

Comment: unrelated - just one small thing about Unity which may be relevant to you if you if the audio is sound effects or the like: as it happens you can't **loop** mp3s in unity, you can only [loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29436196/294884) wav or ogg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `file://` to the start of the filepath has solved this.

Answer (score 1):

I looks like **Track.ogg** is NOT fully downloaded before you accessed the audio file. Use `isDone` to make sure that the audio is **fully** loaded and use `yield return null` instead of `WaitForSeconds(0.1f)` to wait without freezing.
`www.progress < 0.2` is a bad way of doing this.

```
AudioSource audioSrc;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        if(audioSrc == null) audioSrc = new AudioSource();
        StartCoroutine(LoadTrack(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Track.ogg")));
    }

    IEnumerator LoadTrack(string filename)
    {
        var www = new WWW(filename);

        //Wait for file finish loading
        while(!www.isDone)
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("Progress loading {0}: {1}", filename, www.progress);
            yield return null;
        }

        var clip = www.GetAudioClip(false, true, AudioType.OGGVORBIS);

        audioSrc.clip = clip;
        audioSrc.Play();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
```

Not tested but that should do it.

Comment: I've tried your code but I still get the same error.

Also, I'd like to stream the sound so I don't have to wait for all the files to be fully downloaded before I can start playing them, I think that's what the 2nd argument to GetAudioClip should do.